Set-WebConfigurationProperty in IIS not working
So I got this in my Web.config under "Default Web Site/Login"
<system.web>
    ...
    <membership defaultProvider="WebVerifyMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="WebVerifyMembershipProvider" type="someType" WindowsDomainName="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  ...
</system.web>

And running
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath IIS:\ -Location 'Default Web Site/Login' -Filter "system.web/membership/providers/add[@name='WebVerifyMembershipProvider']" -Name "WindowsDomainName"
returns:
IsInheritedFromDefaultValue: False<br />
IsProtected: False<br />
Name: WindowsDomainName<br />
TypeName: System.String<br />
Schema: Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttributeSchema<br />
Value:<br />
IsExtended: False<br />

So if I now want to update the attribute value for WindowsDomainName using this
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath IIS:\ -Location 'Default Web Site/Login' -Filter "system.web/membership/providers/add[@name='WebVerifyMembershipProvider']" -Name "WindowsDomainName" -Value "someDomain" 
I get this warning: "WARNING: Target configuration object 'system.web/membership/providers/add[@name='WebVerifyMembershipProvider'] is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' location 'Default Web Site/Login'."
So how can I update the WindowsDomainName attribute then?

There isn't extensive documentation around the PowerShell cmdlet, but settings not in the schema file might not be fully supported https://github.com/lextm/iis_schema/blob/master/ASPNET_schema.xml
